# Intercambiar los elementos de un Array unidimensional de N posiciones en java

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo ese ejercicio, en el que tengo que cambiar las posiciones del array en ese orden correspondiente, he conseguido cambiar los valor de la primera mitad con los de la segunda mitad, sin embargo no he podido hacer el intercambio en el orden especifico que me piden

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x, i = 0, n = 0;

        System.out.println("digite el numero de posiciones del array");
        x = scr.nextInt();

        int[] array = new int[x];

        for (n = 0; n < x; n++) {
            System.out.println("Digite el numero " + (n + 1) + " en la posicion " + n);
            array[n] = scr.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("El array original es: ");
        for (n = 0; n < x; n++) {
            System.out.println("El elemento en la posisicion " + n + " es: " + array[n]);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        if (x % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println("No se puede hacer el intercambio con numeros impares");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int temp;
        for (n = 0; n < x / 2; n++) {
            temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[n + x / 2];
            array[n + x / 2] = temp;

        }

        System.out.println("El nuevo array es: ");
        for (n = 0; n < x; n++) {
            System.out.println("El elemento en la posicion " + n + " ahora es " + array[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Eso es lo que llevo hasta ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Mejor haz que el arreglo sea parte de la clase y la variable *temporal* también.

```
static int[] array;
static int selected = 0;
```

Ahora crea 2 funciones. Una para seleccionar un elemento el arreglo y otra para escribir el número seleccionado a la posición deseada y seleccionar el número que estaba en esa posición. La primera no es tan necesaria, pero la intención quedará más clara:

```
static void select(int n){
    selected = array[n];
}

static void moveTo(int n){
    int temp = array[n];
    array[n] = selected;
    selected = temp;
}
```

Para facilitar el algoritmo, puedes crear un segundo arreglo que reciba los cambios.

Teniendo en cuenta que el arreglo prácticamente se invierte tienes el código casi listo:

```
int mitad = x / 2;
for (int n = 0; n < mitad; n++) {
    copia[x - n - 1] = array[n];
    copia[n] = array[x - n - 1];
}
```

Ahora será más fácil escribir el algoritmo para ordenarlo:

```
static void sort(){
   int left = 0;
   int right = array.length;
   int half = array.length / 2;
   select(0);
   for (int i = 0; i < half - 1; i++){
       copyTo(--right);
       copyTo(++left);
   }
   copyTo(half);
   copyTo(0);
}
```

Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##jVRNj5swEL3zK6ZIlUizocn2a9VsL1V76KG9pLcoBwcc4tSxkW1SolV@e3YMBgxJtuUAYt4wfvPeDDtyIJNd@ud8ZvtcKgM7DMSFYTx@Mw8uYtooSvZDiBOR2ViQcKI1/CRMwFMQAF7aEMMSYMIsV0CUIsf5IA6acpoYmsIXmNagn3GQLIVcYWI0eqoAex2IAr3GLwT9CwuDcPa1YDylKhrN2yy9jkmeU5FG4RLCUfNS0VhOV17mRiqILBmBNWdzfDzWbGNORWa2GBmPR9ARGJS/uygv/PKna5RgFXopi6M2dB/LwsRVt1xEeu3wU3ChSC1aTdnTxdOyoXGzRCLz4295UcK@I5P8ooS9mgiCzVHza4fbAre54@B4ZtoDOd2Yzn8XVCzbmoZGY4SfsCV8M8DhLdy3OU6kaSdz6zOrTsPHY11lYl1n6HHPYifRZFJR8dzqsPHYcu@g1mqH2@od6oLT1th23PNizVEgX6c97lFUD3e1PJn2J3CRECEorkGimj2oI5EbJSbwlJ6t5Z3rO3hp7MKUZcxQoBxEsadKQkohl5olTAqq8Y3XkvvjW9qJSFQsaGl@2F31zqiSHUf7IyhXHtjbvGm9eeXVdbtG9duQaghjiATeZiO8hUAFcNKyr2DR97E30/0OuvV9Ua/vTg@QOCZMEA5UfwZfHff/8u3YQFTCa7iHV9j2/7T6S@I845hQdGNLEnQeu0aMqoTs10zibAmnggb8OxNFdTho1dWlJetthd9gvZzzfzUsCnqQru2b3dalT@fzQzDDTt/Be/gAH@ETPDwD).

---

Alternativamente puedes usar otro arreglo del mismo tamaño, de este modo no necesitarás una variable intermedia.

También puedes tener el cuenta de que el resultado es lo mismo que ordenar al revés el arreglo, con la primera mitad desplazada. De esta manera puedes crear un algoritmo más compacto y probablemente más difícil de leer:

```
int[] array2 = int[x];

for (int n = 0; n < mitad; n++) {
    array2[x - n - 1] = array[n];
    array2[n] = array[x - (n + mitad - 1) % mitad - 1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void modiArray( int[] array ) {      
   int fin = array.length - 1;
   int aux = array[ 0 ]; 
   int salto = fin;
   for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {  
      int aux2 = array[ fin ];       
      array[ fin ] = aux;
      aux = aux2;
      salto = salto < 0 ? ++ salto * -1 : --salto * -1;     
      fin +=  salto ; 
      if( salto == 0 ) {
         array[ 0 ] = aux;
         return;
      }
   }  
}
```

Para entender como funciona este código, tenemos que analizar la solución del problema, paso a paso.

Primer iteración:

```
7 = 0  -> 7
```

esto lo leemos como,

asigno a la posición "7" (**fin**) el valor de la posición "0" (**aux**)
guardo el valor previo de la misma (**aux2** y luego **aux**).
Esto lo resolvemos fácil con el siguiente código:

```
   int fin = array.length - 1;
   int aux = array[ 0 ]; 
    
   for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {  
      int aux2 = array[ fin ];       
      array[ fin ] = aux;
      aux = aux2;
```

La variable **fin**, tiene el indice de la última posición del array.
En cambio **aux** contiene el valor de la primer posición.
Ya dentro del for, guardamos el valor de la última posición en **aux2**, y cargamos en la última, el valor de **aux**.

Ahora analicemos las siguientes iteraciones:

```
1 = 7  -> 1
6 = 1  -> 6
2 = 6  -> 2
5 = 2  -> 5
3 = 5  -> 3
4 = 3  -> 4
0 = 4  ->
```

Como se puede observar, el valor de **fin**, debe ir cambiando de una forma... "rarita", inicia en "**7**", luego pasa a "**1**", "**6**", "**2**", "**5**", "**3**", "**4**"... el secreto está en reproducir esa secuencia, cosa que logramos con:

```
  salto = salto < 0 ? ++ salto * -1 : --salto * -1;     
  fin +=  salto ;
```

**salto** inicia en "**7**", cuando llega a la primer linea, se evalúa que es menor que "**0**", entonces se devuelve **--salto * -1**, osea, primero decremento el valor de **salto** (**--salto**) y luego lo multiplico por "**-1**", osea pasa a valer "**-6**", en la siguiente iteración, como **salto** valdrá "**-6**", me va a devolver **++salto * -1**, osea primero aumenta en "**1**" y luego la hace positiva, por lo que queda en "**5**"... y así sucesivamente, solo resta el **if** que cuando **salto** toma el valor "**0**", carga el la primer posición el valor guardado en **aux** y termina la ejecución.

Si se complica la interpretación del operador ternario, podemos cambiar por **if**:

```
if( salto < 0 ) {
    salto = ++ salto * -1;
}  
else {
    salto = -- salto * -1;
}
```